# How to access variable in another C# class / view model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have just started playing around with C# and view models and am having difficulty getting the value of a variable outputted to a textblock in the XAML file.

So I have a View Model called ReplayControlViewModel.cs which has:

```
public class ReplayControlViewModel : ABCObservableObject
```

Inside that class I create the following:

```
public string overallBestSessionLap { get => Get<string>(); set => Set(value); }
```

And use it in a function as follows:

```
private void MessageHandler_OnBroadcastingEvent(string sender, BroadcastingEvent evt)
{
  if (evt.Type == BroadcastingCarEventType.BestPersonalLap)
            // record best lap
            overallBestSessionLap = evt.Msg;
}
```

I then have another View Model called SessionInfoViewModel.cs which has:

```
public class SessionInfoViewModel : ABCObservableObject
```

... and an associated XAML file (SessionInfoView.xaml)

I try to access the variable as follows, but nothing gets shown in the GUI....

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding overallBestSessionLap}" Margin="5,1"/>
```

I have tried several variations including putting the class name in front but still doesn't seem to work. I'm sure this must be easy but if someone can tell me where I'm going wrong I'd appreciate it.

Thanks,
Brad

EDIT (Solution): For reference, I found the following code in my **MainWindow.xaml** which gave me a better understanding of how the binding was working.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Broadcasting:SessionInfoView DataContext="{Binding SessionInfoVM}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
<Broadcasting:ReplayControlView DataContext="{Binding ReplayVM}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
```

And in **MainViewModel.cs** it had this....

```
public class MainViewModel : ABCObservableObject
{
    public SessionInfoViewModel SessionInfoVM { get; }
    public ReplayControlViewModel ReplayVM { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SessionInfoVM = new SessionInfoViewModel();
        ReplayVM = new ReplayControlViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to set correct DataContext in your XAML file. We need more code to help you, but I strongly suggest just googling `WPF datacontext` and going forward from there

Comment: @Krzysztof Skowronek Thanks for the tip. After looking at all of the code and doing some Googling I understand this a lot better now. I still have some questions though....

Comment: So from the code I have found on DataContext it looks like SessionInfoView has a binding to SessionInfoViewModel as expected, but that value I need is a part of ReplayControlViewModel. Is it possible to bind to two different view models or do I need to make the variable I need from the ReplayControlViewModel available from SessionInfoViewModel instead?

Comment: Yes, then you will need to create the variable. If that hierarchy doesn't make much sense logically, you can alway create a more top-level view model that will hold both ReplayControlViewModel and SessionInfoViewModel. Then you have to set DataContext to the top-level one

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Krzysztof, good a idea to read up on binding and datacontext in WPF.
Usually a view has ONE datacontext (which can be shared by multiple views).
So somewhere in your code you should have
sessionInfoView.DataContext =

The other thing to note here is change notification. When you set the value of a property the view binds to, you need to raise a PropertyChanged event. The view "listens" to that event and will update the view.

It is atypical to try to change property values from one viewmodel from another viewmodel. To support modularity, viewmodels are intended to be mostly isolated (there a few exceptions though). Viewmodel communication is usually done through a Messenger.

I would recommend looking into a MVVM framework for WPF. There are plenty around like Prism, or MVVM Light. The examples might be helpful and removes some of the "plumbing". But doing some OnPropertyChanged implementation helps to understands WPF better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I fixed the problem by making the variables available in the target view model directly as advised. All is working now.